# Localhost on Xampp not Displaying

Tags: php, xampp

I'm testing xampp setup, and when I enter localhost, the homepage doesn't display. The main port is 80, and SSL port is 443. I've tried removing the index and dashboard files, but that didn't work. PHP scripts are not running correctly.
[image: localhost]

[image: xampp]

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the running xampp instance and the browser window of loaded http://localhost ?

Comment: I've added them to the original post.

Comment: You have installed another application in you computer that uses the same ports like your xampp. Check if you have for example skype ?

Comment: How do I find what program is using the same port?

Comment: if you have skype in your pc it may be using the port 80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start the Apache.....

Comment: The port is blocked. How do I find what is blocking the port?

Comment: click on the config button in front of apache and then select  http.conf. After that search for the "Listen" and change the port to 85 or something Then search for the "ServerName localhost" and give the same no

Comment: Now you can start the Apache

Comment: Listen 85 and ServerName localhost:85 rename it like this in the httpd.conf file

Comment: Also then in the browser search it like this " http://localhost:85" No problem AppliedNumbers :)

Answer (score 1):

XAMPP has all logs in-built. Go to Apache > Logs > Apache (error.log) and do a quick search. In most of the cases you likely want to change the port Apache listens to.

Go to Apache > Config > Apache (httpd.conf) and find `Listen 80`. Replace it with any non-blocked port, i.e. `Listen 8087`. Save the file and start Apache again.

Comment: Is there any data in `index.php`, something like `<?php echo 'hello world';?>` ?

Comment: There is data in. I did get it to work by changing the port to 85.